# How to share volumes across multiple hosts in docker engine swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-engine

Can we share a common/single named volume across multiple hosts in docker engine swarm mode, what's the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: Docker supports a number of volume plugins that can be used to add support for external storage systems. See the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/#/volume-plugins

Comment: Anything new of the subject? Did you found a definitive solution? I found this but it is slightly dated ( https://jaxenter.com/how-to-share-docker-volumes-across-hosts-119602.html ) I was wondering whether solution #2 creating a NFS translator container is still the only/preferred way to go.

Comment: From that list that @MarkO'Connor mentioned, I can vouch for [Blockbridge](https://github.com/blockbridge/blockbridge-docker-volume).

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution myself after having been an avid Docker fan for years now! I still cannot find a solution that works for me with Docker Swarm mode in a local (non-cloud) environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an NFS server setup you can use use some nfs folder as a volume from docker compose like this:

```
volumes:
    grafana:
      driver: local
      driver_opts:
        type: nfs
        o: addr=192.168.xxx.xx,rw
        device: ":/PathOnServer"
```

Answer (score 1):

## In the grand scheme of things

The other answers are definitely correct. If you feel like you're still missing something or are coming to the conclusion that things might never really improve in this space, then you might want to reconsider the use of the typical POSIX-like hierarchical filesystem abstraction. Not all applications really need it (I might go as far as to say that few do). Maybe yours doesn't either.

## In defense of filesystems

It is still very common in many circles, but usually these people know their remote/distributed filesystems very well and know how to set them up and leverage them properly (and they might be very good systems too, though often not with existing Docker volume drivers). Sometimes it's also in part because they're simply forced to (codebases that can't or shouldn't be rewritten to support other storage backends). Using, configuring or even writing arbitrary Docker volume drivers would be a secondary concern only.

## Alternatives

If you have the option however, then evaluate other persistence solutions for your applications. Many implementations won't use POSIX filesystem interfaces but network interfaces instead, which pose no particular infrastructure-level difficulties in clusters such as Docker Swarm.

### Solutions managed by third-parties (e.g. cloud providers)

Should you succeed in removing all dependencies to filesystems for persistent and shared data (it's still fine for **transient** local state), then you might claim to have fully "stateless" applications. Of course there is often always state persisted somewhere still, but the idea is that you don't handle it yourself. Many cloud providers (if that's where you're hosting things) will offer fully managed solutions for handling persistent state such that you don't have to care about it at all. If you're going this route, do consider managed services that use APIs compatible with implementations that you can use locally for testing (for example by running a Docker container based on an image for that implementation that is provided by a third-party or that you can maintain yourself).

### DIY solutions

If you do want to manage persistent state yourself within a Docker Swarm cluster, then the filesystem abstraction is often inevitable (and you'd probably have more difficulties targeting block devices directly anyway). You'll want to play with node and service constraints to ensure the requirements of whatever you use to persist data are fulfilled. For certain things like a central DBMS server it could be easy ("always run the task on that specific node only"), for others it could be way more involved.

The task of setting up, scaling and monitoring such a setup is definitely not trivial, which is why many application developers are happy to let somebody else (e.g. cloud providers) do it. It's still a very cool space to explore however, though given you had to ask that question it's likely not something you should focus on if you're on a deadline.

## Conclusion

As always, use the right abstraction for the job, and pause to think about what your strengths are and where to spend your resources.

Answer (score 0):

From scratch, Docker does not support this by itself. You must use additional components either a docker plugin which would provide you with a new layer type for your volumes, or a sync tool directly on your FS which will sync the data for you.

From my point of view, the easiest solution is `rsync` or more accurately `lsyncd`n the daemon version of rsync. But I never tried it for docker volumes, so I can't tell if it handle it fine.
Other solutions are offered using [Infinit.sh](https://infinit.sh). It basically does the same thing as `lsyncd` does. It's a one way sync. So if your docker container are RW in their volumes it won't match your expectations. I tried this solution, and it works pretty well for RO operations. And not in production. It's still an alpha version. Infinit is also on the way to provide a docker driver. Not released yet. So I didn't even tried it. Too risky.

Other solutions I found but was unable to install (and so to try) are flocker and glusterFS. Both are designed to create FS Volume based on several HDD from several machines. But none of their repositories were working these past weeks.

Sorry for giving you only weak solutions, but I'm facing the same problem and haven't find yet a perfect solution.

Cheers,
Olivier

Comment: `lsyncd` is amazing, but it only offers one-way sync: One source, one destination. For Docker containers running on random hosts of a swarm and writing files, you'd need the same data on all hosts, and one-way sync will not be sufficient.