# Persistent volumes in docker engine swarm mode across multiple nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode

What's the best way to share volumes across multiple nodes  in docker engine swarm mode to achieve data persistence ?

Any references will definitely help .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share volumes across multiple hosts in docker engine swarm mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360686/how-to-share-volumes-across-multiple-hosts-in-docker-engine-swarm-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a view options:

- Glusterfs
- NFSv4
- Ceph

You can mount your data with the '-v' option. Just make sure, the Share is available on all nodes.